# How do I replace list bullets with image icons in a WordPress 4.8.1 sidebar widget?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar, bulletedlist

I have used both example methods here in an HTML5 file successfully. (I have a plain HTML5 file example that demonstrates this but I'm not yet allowed to post more than 2 links.)

Neither of these methods work correctly in the WordPress 4.8.1 sidebar widget for HTML.

I am using WordPress 4.8.1 and the new Custom HTML sidebar widget that comes with WordPress 4.8.1. I am trying to get an unordered list that uses a different image icon for each list item instead of a bullet.

In one website, I tried putting each icon in with the list item using the following HTML:

```
<ul class="follow">
<li style="list-style-type: none;"><img style="display: inline; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 10px;" src="http://stcwdc.org/images/chapter_logo_54pxtype-28x28.png" alt="Small chapter logo" width="28" height="28" /><a href="http://events.stcwdc.org/">Chapter Events and News</a></li>
<li style="list-style-type: none;"><img style="display: inline; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 12px;" src="http://stcwdc.org/images/twitter-letter-icon-28x28-1.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Follow us on Twitter" /><a href="https://twitter.com/stcwdc" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
<li style="list-style-type: none;"><img style="display:inline; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding-right:12px;" src="http://stcwdc.org/images/in.jpg" width="28" height="28" alt="Join our group on LinkedIn" /><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=156478" rel="nofollow">LinkedIn Group</a></li>
</ul>
```

But, except for the top one in the list, that gives me a list with both bullets and the image icon in the middle five list items even though they are list-style-type:none. See the 4th widget down "Follow Us" in the sidebar at [Competition website](http://competition.stcwdc.org/)

In another website I tried a different method. I searched Stackoverflow and found a question and answer from 2010/2012. I tried that code but it isn't working--I get bullets instead of the icons. See the 6th widget down "Follow Us" in the sidebar at [News and Events website](http://events.stcwdc.org/) Perhaps this is because of the newer WordPress, CSS, and the new Custom HTML widget? The model I am using is from ([Different list style image for each li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474536/different-list-style-image-for-each-li))

This is the HTML I am using:

```
<ul class="follow">
<li class="chapicon"><a href="http://events.stcwdc.org/">Chapter Events and News</a></li>
<li class="twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/stcwdc" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
<li class="linkedinicon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=156478" rel="nofollow">LinkedIn Group</a></li>
<li class="pinteresticon"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/stcwdcmb/" rel="nofollow">Pinterest page</a></li>
<li class="rssicon"><a href="http://events.stcwdc.org/feed">RSS Events Feed</a></li>
<li class="rssicon"><a href="http://wdcb.stcwdc.org/STC_Washington_DC_Chapter.xml">RSS WDCB site Feed</a></li>
<li style="list-style-type: square;">Join our <a href="http://wdcb.stcwdc.org/prof-dev/networking/lists/list-annc/">Announcement list</a></li>
<li style="list-style-type: square;">Join our <a href="http://wdcb.stcwdc.org/prof-dev/networking/lists/list-chat/">Chat list</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the CSS I am using:

```
aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget {
    color: #333;
    margin: 9px 0 10px 9px;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul li a {
    color: #2222ac;   /*----Dark blue. ----*/
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul li a:visited { 
    color: #981b1e;   /*----secondary-red-darkest. ----*/
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    text-decoration: #981b1e wavy underline; /* Ignored in CSS1/CSS2 UAs */
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul li a:hover,
aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul li a:focus; { 
    color: #5b616b;   /*--- coal-blue-light  ----*/
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
    text-decoration: #5b616b dotted underline; /* Ignored in CSS1/CSS2 UAs */
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li.chapicon {
    list-style-image:url('http://events.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/chapter_logo_54pxtype-16x16.png');
    list-style-position:outside;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li.twittericon {
    list-style-image:url('http://events.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter.gif');
    list-style-position:outside;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li.linkedinicon {
    list-style-image:url('http://events.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/in.jpg');
    list-style-position:outside;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li.pinteresticon {
    list-style-image:url('http://events.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest_logo.png');
    list-style-position:outside;
}

aside.widget_custom_html div.custom-html-widget ul.follow li.rssicon {
    list-style-image:url('http://events.stcwdc.org/wp-content/uploads/rss.png');
    list-style-position:outside;
}
```

What do I need to do to make either method work in the latest WordPress 4.8.1 sidebar widget for HTML?

Comment: Have you tried setting `list-style-type:` none; for your li elements?

Comment: Yes. I tried that in the first HTML example at the top of this question--I still got bullets. Perhaps, I can try to add that to the CSS in the bottom example.

Comment: Result: I tried adding list-style-type: none; to each li in the bottom CSS example but I still get bullets and no images.

Comment: try adding list-style: none; to the ul and adding background images for the icons to your li's

Comment: I second @VA79's suggestion of using css and background images for your li elements - it's generally the recommended practice instead of using actual images. Could you provide a link to your test environment? If the obvious solutions don't work, its difficult to know whats happening without seeing the rest of the relevant css.

Comment: @VA79, I tried the background image and it worked better for the example in the News & Events website that is linked to in the question. But if you look at it, you'll see I get both bullets and images. I cannot add another link to show how it works correctly in HTML5 because I'm not at reputation 10 yet.

Comment: you have a list-style: square outside !important; on ul li, ul.square li in styles.css at line 1214. these make for the square bullets. plus the images within the li's wich make the second bullets.

Comment: Please post this as an answer and I'll give you credit. Now I need to readjust my other list stylings so they work again.

Comment: FYI, its better to tag questions appropriately so you target the most relevant people. The Wordpress and sidebar tags are irrelevant here are the issue is purely CSS related. Including irrelevant tags such as wordpress could discourage CSS experts from looking at your question if they are not familiar with programming in Wordpress.

Comment: In this case it is entirely related to WordPress and needed WP 4.8.1 expertise. The CSS and HTML were correct for use in an HTML page but the new WordPress 4.8.1 introduced a new sidebar widget called Custom HTML widget. Previously you could put HTML and images in the text widget but the functionality was changed in 4.8 and images were disabled. 4.81 allowed images in a new Custom HTML widget but it definitely handles things differently from when the code is in the main page content. The CSS must target the sidebar widget specifically. I finally solved it last night by figuring how to do that.